# Calculate marginal probability distributions of a dataset

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling, probability, distribution

I have a dataset with 'n' features and a label(binary) corresponding each entry. I am using a predicitive model to predict these labels using those 'n' features. Now, I wish to know the marginal probability distributions of my dataset. Is there any way to do so? I have read one calculates marginal probability distributions of x wrt y, how do people do it in such cases? Do they calculate label wrt one of the feature?